# pfSense quit - File system unknown - harddisk corrupt?

Tags: filesystems, freebsd, pfsense, gparted

I have a pfSense router, and it stopped working. When I connect a monitor the display stays black. When I remove the internal disk and connect it to an Ubuntu laptop, I don't see it in the file manager. I suppose Gparted would be able to recognize the partition, but this is what I get:

[image: File system unknown]

Does this mean the disk is corrupt?

Comment: Try `sudo modprobe  ufs`, restart Gparted and see if it is identified now. Background: `pfsense` is BSD based and with this command, you load kernel support for the UFS file system commonly used on that OS family.

Comment: It turned out that the disk was OK. The monitor stayed black because of the wrong HDMI port - stupid mistake, but better than a hardware problem. Somehow the kernel refused to load and I reinstalled. I now create a backup of the system that I can restore if this happens again.